# AR Foundation 4.0.2 Update issue TestCameraImage using Unity2019.3

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, foundation

I am updating AR Foundation to version 4.0.2 and it broke TestCameraImage script and my project include AR Foundation Samples.

[image: List of errors]

[image: Version I am using]

Comment: use the verified version

Answer (score 0):

You should have read the migration guide [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.0/manual/migration-guide-3.html).

> **XRCameraImage** is now **XRCpuImage**